# Ubuntu 14.10 - ATI Radeon HD 3650 & Steam issues

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, steam

I have just installed Steam on Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) and it seems to be giving me the following error:

OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.
For more information visit https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9938-EYZB-7457.

I have heard that ATI legacy cards are no longer supported and some other shenanigans, I also read something about patched/ported drivers. (Can't remember where exactly...) But I would like to get input from people or possibly some help on how to get the best of my 'old' card... I'm poor so please don't tell me to get buy a new one.

It's  laptop with that card integrated into it, a Dell Studio 1735 to be precise. So please help me out, share any tips you have regarding this issue to help me out, thanks for your precious time and have a wonderful day!